# How would I convert Select Options into a list but keep values?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, html-select

I have a select dropdown list which looks like this:

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/search.html" name="asearch">
<select id="ingredient" name="attributes[3]" onchange="asearch.submit()">
    <option value="16" />Biscuits
    <option value="3" />Bites
    <option value="6" />Bones
    <option value="18" />Chews
    <option value="9" />Popcorn
    <option value="56" />Shanks
    <option value="1" />Sticks
    <option value="140" />Toy</select>
<input type="hidden" name="advanced" value="1" /></form>
```

I want to convert this select box into an unordered list instead, but I need to somehow keep the option values and have the new links link to these values.

So far I've managed to find a small piece of jquery to convert the select dropdown into the list, but when I do so it removes the values as well, meaning all the links just link to nowhere instead. Is there a way of doing this? Keeping the values and somehow converting them to href instead?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be to do it like this

```
$('#ingredient option').each(
function() {
    $('#list').append('<li><a href="/'+$(this).val()+'">'+$(this).text()+'</a></li>');
}
);
```

and the HTML

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/search.html" name="asearch">
<select id="ingredient" name="attributes[3]" onchange="asearch.submit()">
    <option value="16" />Biscuits
    <option value="3" />Bites
    <option value="6" />Bones
    <option value="18" />Chews
    <option value="9" />Popcorn
    <option value="56" />Shanks
    <option value="1" />Sticks
    <option value="140" />Toy</select>
<input type="hidden" name="advanced" value="1" /></form>
<ul id="list">

</ul>
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hkCRX/)

Comment: Thanks. That does work, but the links don't go anywhere. Perhaps what I'm asking for isn't possible. This is a refine search menu for an ecommerce website, so the original option values do actually link to refine product searches. I need the new links to do the same. Either that, or I need to completely change the look of the select box and options to look like normal href links.

Comment: You have to customize the links. I can't know where the links should go and how they look like. You have to know If you can create a proper link with the value (16, 3, 6, 18, 9, 56 ...)